# Service to pull data from Azure Storage to local machine every day

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I have a Azure process that stores some .png files in Azure File storage or Blob storage every 2 hrs. I want to create a service which will run from my machine and pull the latest files every 2 hrs . Please suggest if we can do this by Windows service or if there is any other better solution to Automate this.

Comment: Windows service, scheduled task, or long-running console application. All work. All you need to research to determine the pros and cons of each.

Comment: You could just use Timer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest if we can do this by Windows service or if there is any
>   other better solution to Automate this.

Yes, you could do it with windows service ,this is the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer), it also shows how to add `Timer Event` then you could handle Azure-Storage like normal program.

Or you could choose to use console app, this also could satisfy your requirement. You could use a `Timer` to handle Azure-Storage , however you need to keep this app running all the time.

If you still have questions, please let me know.